# preventing unused symbol from be stripped

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, lldb

There is a function I have written in C that I would like to use in the debugger to send commands to a javascript engine. Since this function is not used directly in code the linker strips this symbol. Is there a way to mark a particular function to not be stripped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/500-Linking/bs_linking.html

declaration should have

```
__attribute__((used))
```